# Is it possible to replace form headers with Markdown in Colab?

Tags: markdown, google-colaboratory

Although I'm new to Colab notebooks, I can't find the answer to this anywhere.

We know that [Colab supports Markdown](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/markdown_guide.ipynb). But, accepting input as a form directly maps to the code-behind with seemingly no way to beautify the form fields into Markdown.

For example, [in this demo form](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/forms.ipynb):

[image]

I want to show "text_and_dropdown" as so: "Text and Dropdown".

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way to customize the label with colab's built-in forms. But I have a workaround for you to consider:

```py
#@title String fields

#@markdown Text
value = 'value' #@param {namelabel: "hihi",type:"string"}
text = value
#@markdown Dropdown
value = '1st option' #@param ["1st option", "2nd option", "3rd option"]
dropdown = value
#@markdown Text and dropdown
value = 'value' #@param ["1st option", "2nd option", "3rd option"] {allow-input: true}
text_and_dropdown = value

print(text)
print(dropdown)
print(text_and_dropdown)
```

Which uses a nice section header in markdown, and a generic name `value` with no space to make it not look too much like code.

[image: colab screenshot]

You can of course replace `value` with `answer` or whatever one-word label you want. If you want to be really creative you can even use unicode in Python 3, like `ᐅ = 'value' #@param`. I'll leave it up to you to decide whether this idea is good, terrible, or evil.

Comment: That's a bit closer, but our customer doesn't want to see code, like, at all. Is it possible to make "value" an empty string maybe?

Comment: We tested and it looks like a custom browser extension could be a valid option to accomplish the above. Unfortunate that the product doesn't offer it as an option.

Comment: Yea unfortunately I don't think Colab is designed with no-code use cases in mind. Browser extension feels like overkill, I would explore other options first if I were you, but maybe it makes sense in your context.